# Vanilla javascript function to round to nearest hundred or 100K, plus symbol

Tags: javascript, math, concatenation, rounding

I am trying to write a single (vanilla javascript) function to round an array of numbers to the nearest 100 if over a thousand, and nearest 100K if over a million, then truncate and a symbol. So an array like this...

```
[ 1158298, 949000, 1493, 51232, 12501, 8426 ]
```

...would return this:

1.2M, 950K, 1.5K, 51K, 13K, 8.5K

This solution for the millions instance works, but feels awfully convoluted and doesn't handle all the instances. I could use if/else and write three versions of this but it seems like there is a more elegant solution?

```
function round(num){
  var roundNum = (Math.round(((num/100000).toFixed(2))) * .1).toFixed(1) + "M"
  return roundNum
}
console.log(round(1158298));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the logarithm of 10 and get the places. Then divide by `3` for the right postfix.

```js
function fn(v) {
    var p = Math.floor(Math.log(v) / Math.LN10),
        l = Math.floor(p / 3);
    return (Math.pow(10, p - l * 3) * +(v / Math.pow(10, p)).toFixed(1)) + ' ' + ['', 'K', 'M'][l];
}

var data = [1158298, 949000, 1493, 51232, 12501, 8426];

console.log(data.map(fn));
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to do it with if/else statements but your solution is more concise.